# UnExpectedException - UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: jetty, rpc, m2e, gwt-maven-plugin

I'm working with a maven-gwt Projekt using m2e plugin.
I implemented a rpc for having access to my server-side datastore.

However starting my webclient gives me an UnsatisfiedLinkError:

```
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.util.List   de.myPackage.client.SearchService.doSearch(java.lang.String,de.myPackage.shared.Coordinate,de.myPackage.shared.Coordinate)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gwtopenmaps.openlayers.client.LonLatImpl.create(DD)Lorg/gwtopenmaps/openlayers/client/util/JSObject;
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:     org.gwtopenmaps.openlayers.client.LonLatImpl.create(DD)Lorg/gwtopenmaps/openlayers/client/util/JSObject;
at org.gwtopenmaps.openlayers.client.LonLatImpl.create(Native Method)
at org.gwtopenmaps.openlayers.client.LonLat.<init>(LonLat.java:26)
at de.iisys.sara2.sara2lightWebclient.server.SearchServiceImpl.doSearch(SearchServiceImpl.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
... 22 more
```

Does somebody knows how to handle this?